# how to group the unique data using array

Tags: arrays, powershell

```
$array =@("1234","2345","3456","5555")

$source = @("1234-abc","1234-xyz","1234-pqr","2345-abc","3456-xyz","5555")

$source | where {
$found=$false

foreach($arr in $array)

{
if($_.contains($arr))

{
$found=$true

$ID=$_

if($found -eq $true)

{

$value=$ID

$myID =@($myID)

$myID=$myID +$ID } } }}
```

=========================

I am getting output like below :
1234-abc 1234-xyz 1234-pqr 2345-abc 3456-xyz 5555

But I need output like below : Application ID + it's related connections so that I can send email to application owner with it's connection names.

1234

abc

xyz

pqr

I need to call email function here to send email to owner of 1234 application with connection names

2345

abc

I need call email function here to send email to owner of 2345 application with connection names
3456

xyz

I Need call email function here to send email to owner of 3456 application with connection names

I have email function ready for it but struggling to get the details in one shot, currently I am sending emails as per application connections i.e. 3mails for 3 connections to same owner

Comment: Consider re-thinking your process here, and building a dictionary/hashtable where the application IDs are the keys into the table, and each key is associated with an array of the values. Microsoft Docs has a good [discussion of hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.1) that might serve as a good starting point for further exploration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggest @JeffZeitlin, you could use a dictionary like that:

```
[string[]]$array =@("1234","2345","3456","5555")
[string[]]$source = @("1234-abc","1234-xyz","1234-pqr","2345-abc","3456-xyz","5555")
$datas = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"[string,string[]]"

foreach($a in $array){
    [string[]]$it = @()
    foreach($s in $source){
        if($s.Contains($a)){
            $it += $s.Split("-")[1] + ","
        }
    }
    $datas.Add($a, $it.Split(",", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))
}

#display result

foreach ($key in $datas.Keys) { 
    Write-Host "Key: $key  $($datas[$key].Count) values -> $($datas[$key])" 
}
Write-Host "**********************"
Write-Host "Other way to display:"
foreach ($key in $datas.Keys) {
    Write-Host "Key: $key"
    foreach ($value in $datas[$Key]){
        Write-Host "$value" 
    }
    Write-Host "--------------------"
}
```